# good layout in 3.5" and bad one in 4.0"

Tags: ios, iphone, layout, xcode5, mkmapview

My first view is a login page with a mapview tha show the user current position. I've a big problem changing from 3.5" and 4.0"; in 3.5 all my elements are show good exactly where I expect them according to the storyboard layout; in 4.0 the scrollview containing login elements appear over the logo and mapview. Any suggest are wellcome

Thanks in advance,
Brunix

Comment: A bit more information is needed before anyone can really help. Are you using auto layout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could theoretically use auto layout however, the better route is to use autolayout in your storyboard. Go into your storyboard, and check the "Use Autolayout" checkbox in the file inspector. Then select the layout in the storyboard, and go to

```
Editor -> Resolve Auto Layout Issues -> Reset to suggested constraints for _____
```

ceck this [documentation](http://www.raywenderlich.com/50317/beginning-auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-7-part-1) for further help

Comment: Mark it correct if it helped you so that others will make use of this too.